# setimageBitmap from URL does not fit the size I want

Tags: android, image, url, bitmap, image-size

I am trying to get an image from URL in Android and set it in a `ImageView`. What I am doing is the following:

```
image = new ImageView(mContext);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MY_WIDTH, MY_HEIGHT);
params.leftMargin = lefMargin;
params.topMargin = topMargin;
image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(MY_URL).getContent());
relativeLayout.addView(image, params);
```

But the image does not fit my size (MY_WIDTH, MY_HEIGHT), It is showed in its own size. What to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you tried this ?

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(MY_URL).getContent();
Bitmap bitmapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, MY_WIDTH, MY_HEIGHT, true);
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapScaled);
image.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: It doesn't if you perform it in an AsyncTask.

Comment: This works for me, I downloaded a static map from google and after I used 'Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()'.

Comment: @sunil Can you show my question because I am trying to follow you answer because I want to take a favicon of saved search url but it is me leading to error this code.
Here is my question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54233815/get-favicon-from-a-web-and-save-it-to-declared-icon-in-a-pojo-class

Answer (score 3):

add this line for ur imageview

```
imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
imageview.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

Comment: It worked. Much more reliable compared to other methods

Answer (score 0):

This may work try out,

```
image = new ImageView(mContext);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MY_WIDTH, MY_HEIGHT);
params.leftMargin = lefMargin;
params.topMargin = topMargin;
image.setLayoutParams(params );
image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(MY_URL).getContent());
relativeLayout.addView(image);
```

Comment: It didn't work! I want to use a RelativeLayout, because I want to display image according to their X and Y coordinates.